# Write empty bytes using binarywriter

Tags: c#, winforms, binarywriter

so i am using binarywriter to write some strings over the original strings, but i need to overwrite the whole string in the binary file, so i am trying to write the new string, and overwrite the rest of the old string with 0x00 (empty bytes), this is what i tried, but not working:

```
bw.Write(enc.GetBytes(listView1.Items[i].SubItems[2].Text + (31 - enc.GetByteCount(listView1.Items[i].SubItems[2].Text)) * '\0'));
```

31 is the constant int that all old strings can't tresspass (don't ask me, it's a script thingy)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's because:

```
number * '\0'
= number * 0  ('\0' converted to int)
=> always equal to 0
```

To generate a string filled with `\0` (or any char) of a certain length, use:

```
new string(`\0`, number)
```

In your case:

```
string newStr = listView1.Items[i].SubItems[2].Text;
bw.Write(enc.GetBytes(newStr + new string('\0', (31 - enc.GetByteCount(newStr)))));
```